# Increase page numbers in LaTeX Beamer

Tags: latex, beamer

in LaTeX Beamer, the total number of slides includes those that only contain the table of contents before each section/subsection, which increases the total number of slides unnecessarily. Is there any way to prevent this?

In other words: I don't want slides containing the TOC to have page numbers.

Kind regards,
mefiX

Comment: there is a special SE site for LaTeX http://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add the line

```
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
```

on each frame you wish to exclude from total count.

See also this [other Question here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732902/ignoring-page-numbers-in-backup-slides), which might assist you further.

Comment: This does not exclude from total count. This only decrease the counter.
It has some bad side effects:
With \usepackage{appendixbeamerpackage}, the counter on the first slide is 0 (while it should not appear), the counter on my last slide prints 12/13 and appendix question slide is 1/13.

Answer (score 5):

The frame option `noframenumbering` will exclude certain frames from increasing the framenumber. I would recommend to use it in combination with the `plain` option, otherwise it might look that the frames with the toc will show the same frame number as the frame before.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\AtBeginSection[]{%
    \begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `[plain]` to not display the header and the footer. Finally, add `\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}`  to not increment page number.

```
\AtBeginSection[]{%
    \begin{frame}[plain]
    \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}
```