# Insert the number of slides up to a final slide in a rmarkdown::beamer_presentation

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown, beamer

In a beamer presentation generated with `rmarkdown::beamer_presentation`, I currently have `\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber` which shows the current page and the total number of slides in the presentation.

How to insert the number of slides up to a "final slide" in the footer instead of the overall "total number of slides"?

*Note:* I would like to refrain from having to add `{.noframenumbering}` to all slides in the appendix.

### MWE

#### Preamble.tex

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \leavevmode%
    \hfill
        \hyperlinkappendixstart{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}
}
```

#### Presentation.Rmd

````
---
title: "Slide counter ends at specific slide"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rmarkdown::beamer_presentation
    latex_engine: lualatex
    toc: false
    slide_level: 2
header-includes:
  - \input{files_beamer/preamble}
---

## Slide 1

## Slide 2

## Slide Final
==> count up to this slide

``` {=latex}
\insertframeendpage
```

## Additional Slide 1 (not counted)

## Additional Slide 2 (not counted)
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your beamer version is up-to-date, you can use the `\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[appendixframenumber]` template. No need for additional packages.

````
---
title: "Slide counter ends at specific slide"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rmarkdown::beamer_presentation
    latex_engine: lualatex
    toc: false
    slide_level: 2
    keep_tex: true
header-includes: |
  \makeatletter\beamer@ignorenonframefalse\makeatother

  \setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[appendixframenumber]

  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \leavevmode%
    \hfill
    \hyperlinkappendixstart{%
      \usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}%
    }
  }

---

## Slide 1

## Slide 2

## Slide Final
==> count up to this slide

``` {=latex}
\end{frame}
\appendix
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Additional Slide 1 (not counted)}
```

## Additional Slide 2 (not counted)
````

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add to the YAML-header:

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
```

(See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1738033/10451245)).

Alternatively one could likely define a new command using something like `\inserttotalframenumber - \insertappendixframenumber` somewhere before `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{...}`.

Comment: If your beamer version were up-to-date and your theme would use the appropriate templates, then you could simply do `\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[appendixframenumber]` No need for any additional packages.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for the hint, will try!